# Metodo System.io.Searchoption con credenciales de acceso a carpeta en red

Tags: c#, consola, net

Buen dia, tengo un método de una libreria en c# que va a buscar todos los archivos dentro de un directorio, el problema es cuando se va a ejecutar el metodo me dice que no tiene acceso por que "El usuario y contraseña con incorrectos", entonces mi pregunta es...

Existe alguna forma de pasarle las credenciales a dicho metodo para que pueda acceder sin problemas?
Tengo un metodo que se llama networkcredentials que contiene las credenciales de acceso a la carpeta en red, pero realmente no se como poder implementarlo, dejo el codigo a continuacion...

`IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories); // Metodo que busca los archivos dentro del directorio`

`NetworkCredential credenciales = (new NetworkCredential("USUARIOPRUEBA", "CLAVEPRUEBA"));` // metodo que tiene las credenciales de acceso...